# Java waiting for client's data pauses application cause of infinite loop

Tags: java

hey I am trying to make a console application that can receive and send messages to the clients.

It will accept multiple clients & handle them.

To add a new client i do this in the run method:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        this.server = new ServerSocket(this.port);
        this.factory = new ServerFactory(this.server);
        System.out.println("Server runs and now waiting for clients");
        this.runClientHandler();
        Socket client;
        while ((client = this.server.accept()) != null) {
            this.handler.addClient(this.factory.createClient(client));
            System.out.println("done");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But "done" will never be printed because of this client's infinite loop for his message:

```
public void handleClient() throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[5*1024];
    int read = -1;
    byte[] data;
    String message;
    while ((read = this.socket.getInputStream().read(buffer)) > -1) {
        data = new byte[read];
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, data, 0, read);
        message = new String(data, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Client message: " + message);
    }
}
```

handleClient() method will run in Thread-2 at handleClients.add():

```
public void addClient(Client c) throws IOException {
    c.writeMessageStream("hey");
    System.out.println("New client!");
    this.clients.add(c);
            //prints here
    c.handleClient();
            //never reaches this..
}
```

How can I ignore the while loop and let the program execute while the while loop runs without making a new thread for each client?

Comment: I got the same on my own IMAPv4 implementation and I was wondering why... But it was over a year ago. I tried it to connect with thunderbird with the infinite loop reason. Edit 2: I googled a lot and some said, that´s because java don´t send line breaks through the client or finishes a sent string.

Answer (score 0):

Check NIO Selectors. They are part of Java NIO in JDK. Or you can use an out-of-the-box solutions like Netty or (worse) Apache MINA.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't be able to handle multiple clients as it is serving the client from the same thread it is accepting connections. Generally, the client connections should be handled by different threads and you may like to use asynchronous IO so that multiple connections can be handled from a single thread. You should use Netty which simplified all these. Here are some example programs http://netty.io/5.0/xref/io/netty/example/telnet/package-summary.html